# PHP CSS Mobile Responsive

Tags: php, html, css, mobile

I am currently working through the challenge of making a page responsive to a number of mobile platforms this includes support for Desktop Browsers, iPhone, iPad, BB10 and BB7.

As you know this isn't always the easiest task.

I have come to the point where I would like each device to use a different CSS file as this makes life easier with the different screen sizes.

I found this PHP script which enables me to direct users to a different html pages... It's great although I don't feel its efficient enough.

Instead I would like to be able to have this script serve the users different .css files based on the device.

I have very little PHP understanding and would appreciate some help here.

---

```
<?php
    // MOBILE
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $blackberry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BB10");
    $blackberry2 = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $iPad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");

    // DESKTOP
    $windows = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Windows");
    $mac = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mac");

    // REDIRECTS 
    // MOBILE
    if ($android == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: mobile.html');
    } 
    else if ($blackberry == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: mobile.html');
    }
    else if ($blackberry2 == true)
    {
    header('Location: mobile.html');
    }
    else if ($iphone == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: mobile.html');
    }
    else if ($ipad == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: mobile.html');
    }
    // DESKTOP
    else if ($windows == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: desktop.html');
    }
    else if ($mac == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: desktop.html');
    }
    ?>
```

---

Comment: A separate stylesheet based on device instead of screen size sounds like a horrible idea to me. It's IE conditionals all over again

Comment: You have to use media queries. Define the style rules based for various `min-width` and `max-width` values. Read more here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your CSS trough the PHP.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.php">
```

Then in your php:

```
<?php
    // MOBILE
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $blackberry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BB10");
    $blackberry2 = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $iPad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");

    // DESKTOP
    $windows = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Windows");
    $mac = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mac");

    // REDIRECTS 
    // MOBILE
    if ($android == true) 
    { 
    include('android.css');
    } 
    else if ($blackberry == true) 
    { 
    include('blackberry.css');
    }
    // others
```

But as the guys in comments wrote - this is not the "modern" approach of responsible css.

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you know of any way I could do this in Javascript opposed to PHP?

Comment: You may test navigator.userAgent and then append link with stylesheet tag.

Answer (score 2):

I want to know why you are using the ancient way, you can use responsive web concept to build the responsive website as per the resolution.

Use twitter bootstrap.js
or 
read this
http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I understand this is definitely not the best way of doing things. 

Without going into too much detail we have no option to do it this way in the current project. 

Thanks